# Tried to add a marathon tag but kept getting replaced by half-marathon

Tags: support, tagging

Is there a way to sort this out?
Half marathon and marathon training are quite different, imho, which is why I'm starting to tag things that way.

Comment: Interesting. I just tagged [a question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/how-should-i-prepare-for-a-marathon-on-an-elliptical-machine) with [tag:marathon]. I don't see any tag synonyms for half-marathon or marathon. Perhaps it's a caching issue?

Comment: Agreed - interesting. Maybe it was just the way I was trying to do it. Have fired in a tag definition for marathon.